# Facebook og:description dynamic but breaking page

Tags: php, html, dynamic, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I'm new here and hoping I can get some help pretty quickly on this very annoying matter!

I'm trying to get the Facebook og:description to work properly when somebody clicks the share button.

The data is being driven dynamically via PHP and the og:title works with the following code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $jsonRow->title; ?>" />
```

but for the og:description tag i'm using the following code;

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo nl2br(strip_tags($jsonRow->details, ?>" />
```

Now the Title works fine and pulls the title field from our database, but the details are pulled, but for some annoying reason the whole lot of data is displaying as text on the webpage!  Is there something i'm missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

If anybody else has an issue, I changed the php a little bit to the following:

```
<meta property="description" content="<php echo strip_tags($jsonRow->details); ?> />
```